# How can I configure the password and username of a ClearDb MySQL database in an ARM template

Tags: mysql, azure, azure-resource-manager, cleardb, azure-rm-template

Is there a way to set the PW and username of a ClearDB MySQL database in an ARM template?

Here's the resource:

```
 {
         "type": "SuccessBricks.ClearDB/databases",
         "name": "[parameters('databases_cmsdbbasic_name')]",
         "apiVersion": "2014-04-01",
         "location": "East US 2",
         "plan": {
             "name": "Jupiter"
         },
         "tags": {},
         "scale": null,
         "properties": {
             "hostname": "us-cdbr-azure-east2-d.cloudapp.net",
             "name": "[parameters('databases_cmsdbbasic_name')]",
             "id": "8C7C711AC0C0A028CE3E9D45814B868A",
             "size_mb": "0",
             "max_size_mb": "10240",
             "status": {
                 "name": "Healthy",
                 "message": "Database is healthy and ready for use.",
                 "level": "Info"
             }
         },
         "dependsOn": []
 },
```

Comment: It seems impossible, the template is provided by ClearDB. This is not determined by Azure. If you really want this function, you had better contact ClearDB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on my knowledge, it is not possible.

Publisher `ClearDB` does not allow user to add user and password information in the template. Currently, the user's name randomly generated by cleardb. It also does not support change user name. You need rest password on ClearDB portal.